# hash filenames into combinations of words

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, hash

Imagine you have a list of very long filenames, eg:

```
[
"01_this_is_a_unnecessary_long_filename_that_I_cant_quite_shorten_arbitrarily.txt",
"this_is_another_unnecessary_long_filename_that_I_cant_quite_shorten_arbitrarily_21473q.txt",
...
]
```

I want to map these filenames to short and more easily memorable, filenames, eg:

```
["flying_dog", "red_bird", ...]
```

Of course, I can create a hash for each individual filename string, then create a lookup table with combination of words from a closed set.

I just wonder if something off-the-shelf exists already?

Comment: You might check out https://pypi.org/project/names-generator/

Comment: You don't need a lookup table as such. Just hash the name and use N groups of M bits of the hash as indexes into a wordlist. N determines the number of words, and M the cardinality of the wordlist. This is how [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) works.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Peter's comment with one possible implementation:

```
import hashlib
from mnemonic import Mnemonic

filename = "01_this_is_a_unnecessary_long_filename_that_I_cant_quite_shorten_arbitrarily.txt"

hash_object = hashlib.md5(filename).encode('UTF-8')
hash = hash_object.hexdigest().encode('UTF-8')

mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
words_code = mnemo.to_mnemonic(hash)

N = 4 # only use first N words; small N will create collision.
slug = '_'.join(words_code.split(' ')[:N])

print(slug)
```

This requires you to install [mnemonic](https://pypi.org/project/mnemonic/) package:

```
pip install mnemonic
```

Mnemonic was designed to create mnemonics for bitcoin wallets.